# How to drop empty responses in an array of fields?

Tags: php, forms

I've got a PHP script to take answers from a referral form and send it by email to my client (below). The client has now asked that only questions that have been answered be sent to them. How can I strip out the fields that are empty from the email?

```
 $from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Web Contact Data-Medical Referral"; 

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"referrer"} = "Referral Source"; 
 $fields{"referraldate"} = "Date of Referral"; 
 $fields{"filenumber"} = "File Number"; 
 $fields{"hearingdate"} = "Hearing Date"; 
 $fields{"legalfirm"} = "Legal Firm"; 
 $fields{"Address"} = "Legal Firm Address";
 $fields{"plantiffattorney"} = "Plantiff Attorney";
 $fields{"plantiffaddress"} = "Plantiff Attorney Address";
 $fields{"plantifftelephone"} = "Plantiff Attorney Telephone";
 $fields{"plantiffemail"} = "Plantiff Attorney Email";
 $fields{"defenceattorney"} = "Defence Attorney";
 $fields{"defenceaddress"} = "Defence Attorney Address";
 $fields{"defencetelephone"} = "Defence Attorney Telephone"; 
 $fields{"defenceemail"} = "Defence Attorney Email";
 $fields{"lawclerk"} = "Legal Assistant/Law Clerk";
 $fields{"lawclerktelephone"} = "Legal Assistant/Law Clerk Telephone";
 $fields{"lawclerkemail"} = "Legal Assistant/Law Clerk Email";
 $fields{"insurancecompany"} = "Name of Insurance Company";
 $fields{"insuranceaddress"} = "Insurance Company Address";
 $fields{"Adjuster"} = "Adjuster Name";
 $fields{"adjusternumber"} = "Adjuster Telephone";
 $fields{"adjusterfax"} = "Adjuster Fax";
 $fields{"adjusteremail"} = "Adjuster Email";
 $fields{"claimnumber"} = "Claim Number";
 $fields{"claimantname"} = "Claimant Name";
 $fields{"gender"} = "Gender";
 $fields{"dateofbirth"} = "Date of Birth";
 $fields{"claimantaddress"} = "Claimant Address";
 $fields{"claimantcity"} = "Claimant City";
 $fields{"claimantpostal"} = "Claimant Postal Code";
 $fields{"claimanttelephone"} = "Claimant Telephone";
 $fields{"lossdate"} = "Date of Loss";
 $fields{"Injuries"} = "Injuries";
 $fields{"Diagnosis"} = "Diagnosis";
 $fields{"reportaddress"} = "Report to Address";
 $fields{"transportation"} = "Transportation Required";
 $fields{"translation"} = "Translation Required";
 $fields{"language"} = "Language";
 $fields{"abilitiesevaluation"} = "Abilities Evaluation";
 $fields{"occupationaltherapist"} = "Legal IME-Occupational Therapist";
 $fields{"rheumatologist"} = "Legal IME-Rheumatologist";
 $fields{"chiropractic"} = "Legal IME-Chiropractic";
 $fields{"opthamologist"} = "Legal IME-Opthamologist";
 $fields{"socialworker"} = "Legal IME-Social Worker";
 $fields{"dental"} = "Legal IME-Dental";
 $fields{"optomertrist"} = "Legal IME-Optometrist";
 $fields{"slp"} = "Legal IME-SLP";
 $fields{"endocrinologist"} = "Legal IME-Endocrinologist";
 $fields{"orthopedic"} = "Legal IME-Orthopedic Surgeon";
 $fields{"tsa"} = "Legal IME-TSA";
 $fields{"ent"} = "Legal IME-ENT";
 $fields{"pediatrician"} = "Legal IME-Pediatrician";
 $fields{"vascularsurgeon"} = "Legal IME-Vascular Surgeon";
 $fields{"gastroenterologist"} = "Legal IME-Gastroenterologist";
 $fields{"physician"} = "Legal IME-Physician";
 $fields{"vocationalevaluation"} = "Legal IME-Vocational Evaluation";
 $fields{"internalmedicine"} = "Legal IME-Internal Medicine";
 $fields{"physiatrist"} = "Legal IME-Physiatrist";
 $fields{"legalfilereview"} = "Legal File Review";
 $fields{"jobanalysis"} = "Legal IME-Job Analysis/WSA";
 $fields{"physiotherapist"} = "Legal IME-Physiotherapist";
 $fields{"lifecare"} = "Life Care Plan";
 $fields{"neurologist"} = "Legal IME-Neurologist";
 $fields{"psychiatrist"} = "Legal IME-Psychiatrist";
 $fields{"lifecarereview"} = "Life Care Plan Review";
 $fields{"neuropsychologist"} = "Legal IME-Neuropsychologist";
 $fields{"psychologist"} = "Legal IME-Psychologist";
 $fields{"other"} = "Other";
 $fields{"otherrequired"} = "Service";
 $fields{"neurosurgeon"} = "Legal IME-Neurosurgeon";
 $fields{"psychovocational"} = "Legal IME-Pyschovocational";
 $fields{"comments"} = "Comments";



 $body="Referral Info:\n\n";


 foreach($fields as $a => $b) {


     $body .= sprintf("%20s:%s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]);
 }


if(empty($fields)) {
     echo 'Please fill in the submission form';
     return false;
 }

$send = mail($email, $subject, $body);

if ($send){
    print "Thank you!";

}else{
     print "Oops!";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work? Or, what approaches have you considered for this task? If you have clients, this seems very basic.

Comment: Most of my coding is HTML, CSS and Javascript. Admittedly, my PHP skills are weak. Barmar's solution worked for me. My approach was similar to his, but embarassingly, I was using the wrong operative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the field is empty before adding it to the mail.

```
foreach($fields as $a => $b) {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST[$a])) {
        $body .= sprintf("%20s:%s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2nd array and only include the values in the $field array that are not empty.

```
<?php
    $arrMail = array();
    if(sizeof($fields))
    {
        foreach($fields as $k=>$v)
        {
            if( !empty(trim($fields[$k])) $arrMail[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    foreach($arrMail as $a => $b)
    {
        $body .= sprintf("%20s:%s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]);
    }
?>
```